# Flutter : chewie player unable to click player controls

Tags: flutter

I copy example and try to do some modify, however I notice that the player controls unable to click / seek

`video_player: ^2.4.5`
`chewie: ^1.3.4`

[image]

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

class VideoView extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _VideoViewState();
  }
}

class _VideoViewState extends State<VideoView> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;
  int? bufferDelay;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializePlayer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<String> srcs = [
    "https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-spinning-around-the-earth-29351-large.mp4",
    "https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-daytime-city-traffic-aerial-view-56-large.mp4",
    "https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-a-girl-blowing-a-bubble-gum-at-an-amusement-park-1226-large.mp4"
  ];

  Future<void> initializePlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(srcs[currPlayIndex]);
    await Future.wait([
      _videoPlayerController.initialize(),
    ]);
    _createChewieController();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _createChewieController() {

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
      progressIndicatorDelay: Duration(seconds: 1),
      additionalOptions: (context) {
        return <OptionItem>[
          OptionItem(
            onTap: toggleVideo,
            iconData: Icons.live_tv_sharp,
            title: 'Toggle Video Src',
          ),
        ];
      },
      customControls: MaterialControls(
        showPlayButton: true,
      ),
      hideControlsTimer: const Duration(seconds: 3),
      // materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
      //   playedColor: Colors.red,
      //   handleColor: Colors.blue,
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      //   bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      // ),
      // placeholder: Container(
      //   color: Colors.grey,
      // ),
      // autoInitialize: true,
    );
  }

  int currPlayIndex = 0;

  Future<void> toggleVideo() async {
    await _videoPlayerController.pause();
    currPlayIndex += 1;
    if (currPlayIndex >= srcs.length) {
      currPlayIndex = 0;
    }
    await initializePlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(secondary: Colors.red),
        disabledColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: IconButton(
            splashRadius: 10.sp,
            icon: Container(
              height: kToolbarHeight,
              width: kToolbarHeight,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_rounded, color: Colors.white, size: 22.sp)
            ),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        extendBody: true,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: _chewieController != null && _chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized ? 
                Chewie(
                    controller: _chewieController!,
                )
                :
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text('Loading'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 100.sp,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove these  ....

extendBody: true,
extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,